# Finding Prime numbers in a list

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program with a call function, to check if between X number and Y number is any given Prime Numbers. if there is it should print them.

I'm stuck with this and don't know how to solve it because it prints all numbers.

```
int isPrime(int number) {
    int flag = 0;
    
    for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

int main() { 
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        
    // run the loop from x to y
    // for each iteration of loop call isPrime()
    for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i) {
        isPrime(i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `if (flag == 0) {...}` block is currently *inside* the `for` loop; it should be after that loop.

Comment: Also, you have declared `isPrime` as returning an `int` but it doesn't. Lying to the compiler is bad.

Comment: @AdrianMole thank you! i still have trouble distinguish **int** from others like **void** (the one i retified).

Comment: @Marco Miguelote: a *FUNCTION* returns a *VALUE* (e.g. "isPrime()" should return an "int").  That's one of the main issues with your code: you forgot the "return".  In C/C++, a "void" function just "does something" - it doesn't return a value back to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code has problems:

- `if (flag == 0) { printf("%d\n", i); }` in the wrong place.  That test needs to be after the `for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i)` loop. [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151714/finding-prime-numbers-in-a-list/77152197#comment136010334_77151714) [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77151735/2410359).
- End of function lacks a return statement. [@Adrian Mole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151714/finding-prime-numbers-in-a-list/77152197#comment136010367_77151714)
- Even with the above repaired, code incorrectly reports 1, 0, -1, -2 ... as *prime*.
- `for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i)` is horribly inefficient.  Test only needs to go to the square root of `number`.

Alternative code:

```
int isPrime(int number) {
  // Check for factors.
  for (int i = 2; i <= number/i; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  if (number > 1) {
    printf("%d\n", number);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

- A more classic idiom would not have `isPrime()` print anything, just return a flag and let the calling code print.
- Since the overall goal is to report many primes, the [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. You need to move your check on the flag to *outside* of the loop, and you just want to return an int representing a boolean value, rather than printing the number.

```
int isPrime(int number) 
{
    int flag = 0;
    
    for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i) 
    {
        if (number % i == 0) 
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    return flag == 0;
}
```

You can then print in `main`.

```
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

An optimization would be to break the loop when you're setting the flag, because you only need to do that once.

```
int isPrime(int number) 
{
    int flag = 0;
    
    for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i) 
    {
        if (number % i == 0) 
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag == 0;
}
```

In fact, the intermediate `flag` variable and the `break` are extraneous when we can instead return that value immediately from the loop.

```
int isPrime(int number) 
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i) 
    {
        if (number % i == 0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

*You will want to deal with the case where you're determining if a number less than 2 is prime. None of the above correctly determines that they are not prime.*

You also know that no factor of N can be more than the square root of N, so there's no point in iterating beyond that. For further optimization, read up on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: but then how does the program print? if there is no printf() ?

Comment: Got my vote but I would suggest using `bool` instead of `int`

Comment: You can also do away with the `flag` variable completely. Just have `return 0;` in place of the `break;` and end the function with `return 1;`.

Comment: Note `isPrime(any_number < 2)` returns 1 where 0 is normally expected.

Comment: @MarcoMiguelote _"but then how does the program print? if there is no printf()"_ : I see a printf in line 3 of the `main` function: `if (isPrime(i)) printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky that comment predates an edit to include that.