# why some functions have return and other not

Tags: c

Why some funtions require `return result` and others don't?

here is a program to calculate simple interest where there is no `return` is in the first function `simpleInterest()` :

```
double simpleInterest(double principal, double time, double rate) {
    double result = ( principal * time * rate) / 100;
}

int main() {
    // take input for principal, time, and rate
    double principal, time, rate;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &principal, &time, &rate);

    // call simpleInterest() with arguments: principal, time and rate
    double interest = simpleInterest(principal, time, rate);

    // print simple interest
    printf("%.2lf", interest);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a program to calculate the are of a circle where it is required to have a `return result` in the first function `computeArea()`:

```
double computeArea( double radius, double pi) {
    double result = pi * radius * radius;
    return result;
}

int main() {
  
    double pi = 3.14;
    
    // get input value for radius
    double radius;
    scanf("%lf", &radius);

    // call computeArea() with arguments radius and pi
    double area = computeArea(radius, pi);

    // print returned value up to 2 decimal points
    printf("%.2lf", area);

    return 0;
}
```

Why both work but one requires `return` and the other doesn't?

Comment: Both need a `return`. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: I do think `simpleInterest` also requires a `return`. Why do you think one requires a `return` and the other does not?

Comment: When you compile, run, debug, and observe the results of these different examples, what do you observe?  For example, in the first one, what value does `double interest` in the `main()` function have?  What value did you expect it to have?  Why?

Comment: You already got *MULTIPLE* replies to this *EXACT* question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77152197/421195.  With respect to "why don't I need a return?" - if you enabled warnings, the compiler would *TELL* you to add the "return".  Currently, your program exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That's Bad...

Comment: @paulsm4: This is not a duplicate of that question. This one asks why `simpleInterest` works (in OP’s observation) even though it does not have a return statement. The other one asks why a program with an `if` in the wrong place does not work.

Comment: @David: Re “When you compile, run, debug, and observe the results of these different examples, what do you observe?”: The question asks “Why both work,” which implies OP did compile, run, and observe the results of these different examples, and it did not answer their question, nor do the questions in your comment lead to answers given the fact the program appears to work for OP.

Answer (score 3):

If the return value of a called function is used by the calling routine but the called function returns because program control flowed to its closing `}` (so no `return value;` statement was executed), then the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

A variety of behaviors are possible, including the program crashing or “misbehaving” in various ways. One possible behavior is that the last calculated value in the called function is used as the return value. This can occur because of how processor registers are used:

- Commonly, to implement returning a value from a function, one of the processor registers is designated to be used for the return value. The called routine should place the value to be returned in the register, and the calling routine should expect to find the return value in that register.
- It is common that a compiler will also use that register for calculations within the called routine. This is natural, since the register’s previous value does not need to be preserved, so it is available for any use until the function returns.
- So, given `double result = ( principal * time * rate) / 100;` as the only code in a function, the compiler might use the designated return-value-register to compute `( principal * time * rate) / 100`. Then, when the function returns, that computed value is left in the return-value-register as an artifact of the fact the register was used to compute the value, not by design of using it to return a value. So the calling routine gets the value you wanted it to get, even though a `return` statement is missing.

While this behavior is not uncommon, it is fragile. If you compiled with optimization enabled, the compiler would likely not generate instructions to compute `( principal * time * rate) / 100` at all, because that expression has no effect on the semantics of the program as defined by the C standard. When you ran the program produced by compiling with optimization, it would not behave as if the value you wanted were returned from the function.